# Sitecore Experience Editor main.js 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, experience-editor

Sitecore will not load the ribbon in experience editor. I constantly get this message

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) speak/v1/assets/main.js
```

Sitecore has permission to access this file.
I also get the following error in the log file.

```
14464 08:02:29 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: ComponentArt.Web.UI
   at ComponentArt.Web.UI.ScriptHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I have no idea why this has started happening now. So all I now see is the spinner and nothing else

Installed Sitecore version: 8-update 5

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? Seems like we're facing a similar issue.
Only difference is a 401 and speak related path's from the config are not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that the configuration file **`App_Config\Include\.Sitecore.Speak.Important.config`** exists in your web root.

I have seen an issue with the Experience Editor if this file is not included.

Comment: Would be worth contacting Sitecore support with this they'd be able to assist you further in debugging the issue.